# I can not touch the image when using UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I use a UIScrollView to show a serial of `UIImageView`(the `UIImageView` is added as subview of `scrollview`), the problem is that I have rewrote the method in `UIImageView`:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

But when I click the image , the method is not called, it seems that the image did not receive the click event. What is the exact reason? How can I fix this?
     (I have enable the exclusiveTouch of the UIImageView and the User Interavtion of all the view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

and if you just want a tap event for the imageview

just use the **UITapGestureRecognizer**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

then you must implement the method

```
- (void) tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    UIImageView *v = gesture.view;// that your ImageView tapped
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the UIImageView's `exclusiveTouch` and `userInteractionEnabled` properties to `YES` and try again.  I find that subviews of scrollview's receive only some or no events, and setting exclusiveTouch allows the view to claim them immediately.

Answer (score 0):

imageView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;